# Loop through hashmap to create a class instance with inside functions

Tags: java, hashmap, bukkit, mcstats

I am making a bukkit plugin, and I am using an API called MCStats, to create the graph, you add Plotters like so...

```
mobs.addPlotter(new Metrics.Plotter("Player") {

    @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return 0;
        }

});
```

But I want to get the values from a HashMap, and idealy something like this...

```
for(String mob: mobNames) {
    mobs.addPlotter(new Metrics.Plotter(mob) {

        @Override
            public int getValue() {
                return Stats.getValue(mob);
            }

    });
}
```

But obviously, it can't access the mob variable, if I set it to final, it still wont be able to change in the loop. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: why does `getValue()` here not use the mob name passed to the Plotter constructor?

Comment: Why doesn't setting the loop variable as `final` work? Doing so will cause it to change each iteration, but not *within* each iteration.

Comment: @sjr - Passing `mob` to the constructor does not create a new scope for the name; the reference to `mob` in `getValue` is to the loop variable, not to the constructor parameter. OP's problem is that an inner class cannot reference a local variable unless it is `final`.

Comment: @TedHopp, I realise that, it's just that the Plotter class probably has a method to obtain the mob name which he should consider using instead of making the variable final.

Comment: @sjr i considered this, but because its not an API that i created, i'd rather not tamper with it, so i can update the API (its a class that i copy in) without having to edit other code.

Comment: @sjr - Ah. I misunderstood your comment. Using something like `getPlotterName()` instead of referencing the variable would be a nice solution (assuming `Metrics.Plotter` had such a method in its api).

Comment: ya, exactly, except in this case there's no such method so the accepted answer is the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, in fact, use `final` in an enhanced `for` loop:

```
for(final String mob: mobNames) {
    mobs.addPlotter(new Metrics.Plotter(mob) {

        @Override
            public int getValue() {
                return Stats.getValue(mob);
            }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't actually know this :P i thought it literally meant it could no longer be changed

Comment: @DanSpiteri -- The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) describes how the compiler translates an enhanced `for` loop into a basic `for` statement. The loop variable ends up as a variable declared _inside_ the basic `for` loop body, so it gets re-declared each time through the loop (as a `final` variable, if you have that modifier).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the final keyword for mob and it still be changed in the loop.
Try to run this code below:

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] data = new String[] {"1", "2"};
        List<MyClass> test = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
        for (final String word: data) {
            test.add(new MyClass() {
                @Override
                public void testMethod() {
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            });
        }
        for (MyClass myClass: test) {
            myClass.testMethod();
        }
    }

    static class MyClass {
        public void testMethod() {

        }
    }
}
```

The output will be "1" and "2".